# Cannot Ping Or Remote Desktop into Hyper-V PC Via IP Address On Host

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I  have a bit of a bizarre problem. I have a Hyper-V VM and I cannot connect to it via IP address on the host computer.

I intend to use it as an SQL server to host a database for a website while I test it, and the first step I can see in this endeavour is to make sure the IP addresses work externally.

Other PCs on the LAN appear to be able to connect just fine via the IP address on Remote Desktop. I cannot do so. I also cannot connect through SQL Management Studio (named pipes or TCP/IP). Although named pipes gives an error relating to being denied access as opposed to IPs which are just not found.

I have tried pinging both ways:

VM => Host : Always gives a "Destination Host Unreachable" error

Host => VM: Always gives a "Request Timed Out" error

As for netstat -a -n, I can see that the VM is listening to 3389 (default Hyper V port, which makes sense).

Regarding Firewalls, all have been turned off on all machines. I can tell that the firewall is not the issue.

If you need any more information to help me to diagnose and treat the problem, please ask me as I would like to get this sorted as quickly as possible.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So the Hyper V is connected as bridged to the lan, and you want to connect from the host to the guest using the guest ip?

Comment: The Hyper V machine is connected to the main LAN, and want to connect via that address from the host, yes.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, did you use external virtual switch mode for the VM?

"Destination Host Unreachable" error means it can't find a entry to route package, "Request Timed Out" error from host also is related to the former cause, it didn't receive the reply.

Did you set a default gateway address for the VM? please emphasis to check the VM ip setting.